# Sublime Text: keyboard shortcut to select a function and its content

Tags: ubuntu, sublimetext2, keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext, sublimetext3

```
function whatever(){
    var = a;
    return a;
}
```

Is there any shortcut to select all of the above code?

I know <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> will select the content within the parenthesis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using JavaScript, you might want to check out the [Expand Selection to Function (JavaScript)](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Expand%20Selection%20to%20Function%20%28JavaScript%29) plugin, available via Package Control. Once installed, there should be an **`Expand Selection to Function (JavaScript)`** option in the **`Selection`** menu, as well as in the Command Palette. The initial keybinding for the function is <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd>, but that didn't work for me running Ubuntu under VMWare Fusion (OS X host), so I added an option to **`Preferences -> Key Bindings-User`**:

```js
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+g"], "command": "expand_selection_to_function_javascript" }
```

If the file is empty when you open it, surround the above command with square brackets `[]`. I chose <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> because is wasn't bound to anything else. If you're running Ubuntu as your only OS (i.e., not as a virtual machine), then <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>↑</kbd> may work just fine.

The plugin itself actually works quite well. Given the following function:

```js
function foo(bar, baz) {
    return bar + baz;
}
```

or:

```js
foo: function (bar, baz) {
    return bar + baz;
}
```

or even an anonymous function:

```js
function() {
    alert("FUBAR!");
}
```

you can click on the `function` keyword, the function name, or anywhere inside the function, hit the key binding, and everything will be selected.

Comment: Nice. So for other languages we just have to look for a similar package I guess...